# GridLayout from Support Library doesn't work correctly on API 16-17

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-gridlayout

I need to create smth like calculator keyboard. `GridLayout` is ideal for it (and only for it :) ). So, I use the one from Support Library (`compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.0'`. Here is my xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:columnCount="4"
        app:rowCount="4"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        app:rowOrderPreserved="false"
        app:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button android:text="7"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="9"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="←"
            android:id="@+id/button_backspace"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>

    <Button android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="6"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="@string/clean"
            android:id="@+id/button_clear"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>

    <Button android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="3"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_clear_all"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:text="@string/clean_all"
            app:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:background="@color/calculator_button_separator_color"
            android:textColor="@drawable/light_button_text_color"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:text="0"
            app:layout_columnSpan="2"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="."
            android:id="@+id/button_dot"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

On Android 4.3-4.4 all is okay:

[image]

But there are troubles on Android 4.1-4.2:

[image]

So, I cannot understand where is my bad.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it was really bug in the support library. I replaced compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.2.0' with compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.0.+', made some magic with code, checked on 4.1 and 4.3 and now it's working!

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:columnCount="4"
        app:rowCount="4"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
        app:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button android:text="7"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="8"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="9"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="←"
            android:id="@+id/button_backspace"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>

    <Button android:text="4"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="5"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="6"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="@string/clean"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:id="@+id/button_clear"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>

    <Button android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="3"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_clear_all"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="@string/clean_all"
            app:layout_rowSpan="2"
            android:background="@color/calculator_button_separator_color"
            android:textColor="@drawable/light_button_text_color"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="0"
            app:layout_columnSpan="2"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
    <Button android:text="."
            android:id="@+id/button_dot"
            app:layout_gravity="fill"
            app:layout_columnWeight="1"
            app:layout_rowWeight="1"
            style="@style/CalculatorButton"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: What magic?  Would you please show only the changed XML so we can learn more easily from your experience?  Thank you!

Comment: @cxw I've only added layout_gravity to all buttons. Maybe, there is other solution, but it is what was useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

or try to create a Adapter and add the datas to the GridView by that

Comment: You have to elaborate a little bit your answer. Throwing an "answer" with only code doesn't help to OP to know what were his mistake, so elaborate a little bit to help him. Thanks.

Comment: @Vishnu T B as I see, Design Support library doesn't contain GridLayout. Or you meen something else?

Comment: I don't have that much reputation to comment that's why i posted @Skizo

Comment: It doesn't matter you can elaborate your answer, doesn't matter the reputation

Comment: @Bringoff I have used gridlayout in my app and all i ever used was this design library.

Comment: @Vishnu T B maybe, you meen cardview.

Comment: CardView is one thing, GridView is another, and GridLayout is a completely different thing. Importing stuff just because _you think_ you need it is the wrong approach, not only will you get new manifest items merged from the design lib, but you will also get a ton of references (reference count on Android is limited to 56k without multi-dex).

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any error on LogCat?

If you are not getting nothing on it try to import `gridlayout-v7`

```
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:19.0.0'
```

Also get sure that you've got a 8+ `minSdkVersion`

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Do you have tried to replace the `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` to `GridLayout`?

Comment: I have imported gridlayout, but 19 version doesn't support column and row weight, so I use 22 version. MinSDK is 14 in build.gradle. I cannot use standart GridLayout because it supports weights only from API 21.

Comment: When you followed my steps did you rebuild / clear project?

Comment: well, yeah, but something I made before your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed this bug in my project. Adding `android:layout_width="0dp"` and `android:layout_height="0dp"` for all buttons solves the problem. Here are parts from my layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:padding="16dp"
    app:columnCount="4"
    app:rowCount="5"
    app:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:text="Test"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"/>

    ...

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```